# Compatibility of DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest in different versions of spring mvc

Tags: java, spring

I have encountered the problem when I want to upgrade the spring mvc from 2.5.3 to 4.x. In 2.5.3, the class "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest" has a contructor

```
"public DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest(
            HttpServletRequest request, Map multipartFiles, Map multipartParameters)".
```

But in 4.2.9, the contructor has changed to

```
public DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request, MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile> mpFiles,
            Map<String, String[]> mpParams, Map<String, String> mpParamContentTypes).
```

I have a customized MultipartHttpServletRequest which extends the "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest" in my own module.
if we upgrade the version to 4.x, we must modify the contructor of our own class.
But I hope this customized class could be available both for spring 2 and spring 4.x.

There are some other method in DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest class which also have compatibility issues, such as `protected final void setMultipartFiles(Map multipartFiles)`

Does anyone have any ideas about that?

Comment: You would need multiple versions or don't extend that class but implement the interface `MultipartHttpServletRequest` instead (and maybe extending the `AbstractMultipartHttpServletRequest` instead).

Comment: I want to develop a single module which provides the customized MultipartHttpServletRequest for applications with different spring mvc versions.  Put multiple versions of spring mvc modules into a single application may cause runtime exception(class conflict). The interface MultipartHttpServletRequest also has compatibility problem. e.g the method "getFileMap" in different versions of spring mvc has different return type.